# How to debug a HRESULT: 0x80131047 compile error

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly, asp.net-3.5

So I have this web project that I downloaded and for some reason it wont let me compile. Gives the error:

The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

I know all the common reasons for that. Special characters in the path, etc. I check that, and did a LOT of googling. All of the answers point to special characters in the path except:

[Unity application block 2.0 - The given assembly name or codebase was invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952109/unity-application-block-2-0-the-given-assembly-name-or-codebase-was-invalid)

Which doesn't help because this is not a runtime error, but fails to compile.

I need to know how to debug this? How can I tell what assembly is causing this error because there are literally hundreds and there is no way I can just do process of elimination.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please show a stack trace, more exception details (inner exception or other properties).

Comment: @fejesjoco its compile error NOT runtime, so no stack trace.

Comment: Run your build with msbuild.exe, and pass a /v:diag command-line switch to it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'll mark yours as the answer if you post. Its just what I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the verbosity of the build under Tools -> Options, Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run. Then view the contents of the output window (View -> Output, Show output from: Build). With any luck the antecedents of the error are in there. You can also try running MSBuild from a developer prompt.